# Formatting two arrays with a correlation Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, format

I am trying to write a numpy function where `Numbers` and `value` are in correlation with each other and
if the element of `Numbers` array is smaller than the `value` element than it will return the number 0 if the case is otherwise the returned number will be 1. If the numbers are equal it will return 2. So the first element in `Numbers` and `value` is 3 and 2, since the `Numbers` value is greater than `value`s number it will return 1. I would like to avoid for loops and list comprehensions if possible.

```
import numpy as np

Numbers = np.array([3,8,10,14,28,42])
value =   np.array([2,4,12,13,30,42])
```

Expected Output:

```
Result = np.array([1,1,0,1,0,2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
>>> np.select(condlist=[Numbers>value, Numbers<value, Numbers==value],
              choicelist=[1, 0, 2])

array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```